# Getting NSTableCellView inside tableView(_:heightOfRow:)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I understand that you cannot call `view(atColumn:row:makeIfNecssary:)` from within `tableView(_:heightRow:)`.

Ideally I'd like to derive height based on a button state within the `NSTableCellView`. I can think of a couple ways to work around this.

- Use `objectValue` in my custom `NSTableCellView` to keep track of the state of the button.
- Only enable buttons on selected row items and maintain a list of the selected `NSTableCellView`.

Are these recommended or is there another recommended way to handle this.

Also, is it recommended for a `NSTableCellView` to know what row/col it belongs too? Or is this something that also should be maintained in `objectValue`?

My use case is will have a disclosure arrow to expand the cell. I've tested it out and it works, however at this point, I'm using a test flag variable to control the height values not the actual button state.

Comment: Have you tried Automatic Rowheigth?

Comment: I referred to the release notes for `usesAutomaticRowHeights`. I think the use case for that would be, for example, an `NSTextField` that needs to grow taller based on new entry of data. Constraints are needed for it. In my case (it may have not been clear in my posting), I want to grow the cell to show more details. This would mean I would need to either grow the frame or do something else which would then induce it to want to auto adjust the row height. I will try and experiment with this, but upon prelim reading, it doesn't seem like a good fit.